# How to root samsung Galaxy Note 2014 edition?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I searched the forum but there was no entry for my specific device.

I have an unlocked Galaxy note 10.1, 2014 LTE edition which I'd like to root. Motivations include ability to install a Linux virtual machine and getting rid of the enormous amount of firmware installed (plus remapping the keys, etc).
So I wanted to ask

1-How I can root my device.

I also have a few related questions whose answers I couldn't find by searching the internet:

2-If I root, will I be using the same OS that I have now, just with superuser access, or would I get "vanilla Android"? I saw a video on youtube about rooting the same device but it needed downgrading to a lower version of Android??? Among samsung's firmware I only use those for the S pen, and I'd like to have them available after rooting.

3-It seems that I need special PC programs for rooting my device. Is there any such software for Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you invested enough time in searching the internet? I just found [this forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1831173) and [another forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1831152) after one search. To answer your other questions:

1. In short, you will need to use ODIN (a computer-based tool used for writing to your device while in "pre-Android" mode) to flash (a fancy phrase for installing) a custom recovery (ClockworkMod, aka CWM). That custom recovery will allow you to flash a superuser app that will handle granting root access. All files necessary can be found by resorting to the linked forums since SO can't host files.
2. rooting does not remove your version of Android. In most cases, it will actually wipe all of your data (factory reset), so make sure to backup anything that you need beforehand. Being rooted does leave room for flashing different versions of Android if you wish to do so in the future.
3. Sadly, I didn't have any luck finding Linux drivers for the Note 10.1. Windows drivers available [here](http://stockroms.net/file/Drivers/Samsung/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe).

Comment: Thank you very much. I found this guide: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/root-samsung-galaxy-note-10-1-2014-lte-p605-cf-auto-root-tool/  but still don't understand what ROM they use and also wanted to see if anybody here has done this successfully.

Comment: From looking at the forum you linked to, there is no ROM that you're flashing. You're simply flashing a root package (as explained in point 1 of my answer). If you want to talk to others who have 'done this successfully', I would recommend that you try other sites, like XDA, or find a walk-through video on YouTube. SO is really meant for questions like "what problem (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?".